# Updating password for an online subscribed calendar programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I have an application where the user can subscribe to an online calendar, which is done by opening an URL with username and password as components. The problem that I have is that when the user changes the password, the local subscribed calendar is not notified in any way, therefore it uses the old credentials which eventually block user's account due to too many falling attempts.

I was unable to find any substantial solution for this issue. Is there anything that could fix it?

Comment: Is it your app that is accessing the calendar? If so, it should get a 403 http status if the credentials aren't valid

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe those changes if any happens or as soon as change happen it must notified to you so that you can update the same.

Comment: Yes but how could I access the subscribed calendar in order to change the password?